# unknown error installing scrapy in pycharm on windows 10

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I'm trying to install scrapy in my project virtual environnement in pycharm and i'm having the following error. ( this is the last few lines of the error log it is quite long )

I don't know what is wrong or what to look for.

I tried to install it using the package manager and the `pip install scrapy` command and the result is the same.

can you help me? thank you and have a nice day!

```
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.8
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src\twisted
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src\twisted\test
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -IC:\Users\XXXXX\PycharmProjects\scrapicerie\venv\include -IC:\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
raiser.c
C:\Python\Python38-32\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier includeÿ: 'io.h'ÿ: No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it had something to do with visual studio. 
I reinstalled visual studio with the python and c++ module and now scrapy installed correctly in pycharm.